# Restore one table from a database in PostgreSQL and save it with plain/text data format

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (tst2) in a database (tweets) in PostgreSQL  and I need to have a plain/text format file out of it, I was wondering if there is any possible solution with `pg_dump` ? something like :

```
pg_dump -t tst2 tweets -f plain >...
```

also if I am in a wrong way please let me know?!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What kind of text do you need? CSV or What?

Comment: edit your question adding copy of the **message error**. Also, for better explanation for us, say if you want restore (`pg_dumo > file.sql` produce a backup file and `psql < file` restaure it)

Comment: thanks I needed CDF or CSV ,and I solved the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to dump a table into a text file.

First, you can use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html), as you intended. In that case you'll get a SQL script to restore the tables. Just fix your command a bit:

```
pg_dump -t tst2 -t tweets -F plain >...
```

Second, you can dump contents of a table with `copy` command. There are either [SQL version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html) of the command (files will be created on the server):

```
copy tst2 to 'tst2.txt';
copy tweets to 'tweets.txt';
```

Or client-side [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html) version (files will be created on your client computer):

```
\copy tst2 to 'tst2.txt';
\copy tweets to 'tweets.txt';
```

Answer (score 1):

pg_dump works for me, though there is some clutter before and after the table (after all, dumps are supposed to be used to fill up the table at recovery time).

I'm not sure what you use the > operator for; the dump goes to the file `plane'.

Your error message would help, of course.

On the other hand, what's wrong with using psql with a .pgpass password file and setting the PGDATABASE, PGHOST, PGPORT, and PGUSER anvironment variables, e.g.:

```
export PGDATABASE=tweet
# PGHOST, PGPORT, and PGUSER as per your setup
psql -c 'select * from tst2'
```

Comment: the error was solved ,I will also try your solution, thanks